# iPad translucent status bar?

Tags: ipad, statusbar

Is there no way to make the status bar translucent for the iPad. I get this error when trying to do this: UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The iPad doesn't support the translucent status bar.

> On iPad devices, the UIStatusBarStyleDefault and UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent styles default to the UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque appearance.

It's probably Apple considers the screen is so big that giving 20px (2 ~ 3% of screen size) to the status bar doesn't really matter.

Comment: It doesn't really matter I agree, but would be cool if we cold use it if we wanted to

Answer (score 1):

Bizarre. If you write an HTML app with the following meta tag and add it to your home screen, the bar actually IS translucent:

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">`

Comment: What iOS version are you on, maybe it has been added since I asked my question?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the value "Transparent black style (alpha of 0.5)" for the key "Status bar style" in the application's plist it will work on launch.  As long as you aren't planning on changing it later between opaque and transparent, this is a viable solution.