# when i pick image from Photos Library in iPad using UIImagePicker, simulator getting crashed

Tags: iphone

```
-(void) pickImage{
 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
  picker.delegate = self;
   [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
   UIImage *myImage =image;
}
```

when `pickImage` meth called simulator crashing and showing message in terminal as below:

```
2012-09-08 18:53:50.953 NewExample[4645:207] UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device.
```

any idea?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent any where ? And which device you're using an iPad or simulator ?

Comment: No, i didnt used UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent any where, And i'm using iPad Simulator 5.0.

Comment: And In iPhone Simulator its Working fine.

Comment: Just check these links. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224243/crash-ipad-photo-picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224243/crash-ipad-photo-picker) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949009/uistatusbarstyleblacktranslucent-is-not-available-on-this-device-ignoring-uist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949009/uistatusbarstyleblacktranslucent-is-not-available-on-this-device-ignoring-uist) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887144/ipad-translucent-status-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887144/ipad-translucent-status-bar) iPad doensn't support the `UIStatusBarSty

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you could not present image picker from the simulator. Validate whether the camera is available for the device and present image picker view.